# Mysql encrypted database contents by proxy?

Tags: mysql

Forive the amateur nature of this question. I work with Wordpress, often transforming the vanilla flavour into custom made versions for clients.

Increasingly clients require more and more marketing information, which often includes entering traffic source conversions, contact data, measuring performance by users etc. Also the amount of lead generation that is happening on these sites increases too.

I looked for some solutions, including encrypting informations but this would always mean i have to hack each and every plugin, and of course the wordpress core which is something i want to avoid and there seems to be the same problem, that decryption files would still be on the server giving a hacker the means to decrypt. (for easy solutions)

So my question:

Is there some better server based utility where i can simply specify the database path, username and password to some utility that encrypts and decrypts information from another database as data is passed to it?

This would be a tidy way of encryping this information. I could specify a database elsewhere with much harder security and specify some sort of proxy database setting in the wp file.

Any ideas? What i am looking for is a super clean and easy way for very very basic server admins to increase the encyption of data inside wordpress in a universal method, ie works for all datas, no need to modify any wordpress plugins or core etc.

Comment: "Encrypted" is not the same thing as "secure."  What is the *specific* threat you're trying to protect against?